# Bloomberg data into Power BI

Tags: powerbi, bloomberg

Have seen a few mentions on pulling Bloomberg pricing data into Power BI, with most referencing a REST API but I can't seem to find any good examples on how to implement. I have a Bloomberg license, but have been struggling on how to marry the two without pulling Bloomberg data into Excel and then referencing in Power BI. Anyone have any luck on this front?

I'd prefer to avoid the Excel route as I'd like to be able to choose dates, assets, etc in the Power BI report and then refresh dynamically rather than open Excel every time and then refresh the Power BI report.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't speak to the specifics of how Bloomberg's data is setup, but there are other examples of using PowerBI to connect to REST services using the Web.Contents connector. I've gotten data out of Google Maps and SharePoint like this.

Comment: Try referring this web link https://zappysys.com/blog/howto-import-json-rest-api-power-bi/?gclid=CjwKCAjwq4fsBRBnEiwANTahcBs0LMhN2XUWZww9odxuYaN_or2PiGamDxmAVmGr7bIwj1GPuXHklhoCoWEQAvD_BwE Which seems quite useful for your question...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a way to load data via `R` with the `Rblpapi` library. Might try going down this route. I don't have a license so I'm unable to test.

Documentation here:
http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rblpapi.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll be glad to know that Bloomberg Connector is part of Power BI April release !

Answer (score -1):

There does not currently seem to be an easy way of doing this. I have been exploring using C#. I found [this tutorial](http://holowczak.com/bloomberg-api-csharp-subscriptions/) which provides a lot of detail on connecting to the Bloomberg API using C#, and [this tutorial](https://chris.koester.io/index.php/2017/11/05/push-data-into-power-bi-streaming-datasets-with-csharp/) on pushing data into Power BI using C#. There might be a way by connecting the concepts in both tutorials. If anyone has any better ideas I would love to hear them.